# Unable to gather datastore facts with vmware_datastore_info module

Tags: ansible, vmware, datastore

I'm trying to collect the VMware datastore info from the ansible module `community.vmware.vmware_datastore_info` with the below task and debug the same:

```
    - name: Gather info from datacenter about specific datastore
      community.vmware.vmware_datastore_info:
        hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
        username: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        datacenter_name: '{{ datacenter_name }}'
        name: ENV04
        validate_certs: False
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: info

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ info }}"
```

The debug task is returning the below output:

```
TASK [Gather info from datacenter about specific datastore] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.17.92.2 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.17.92.2] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "datastores": [],
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

Rather than the one mentioned in the ansible-doc for this module:

```
RETURN VALUES:
- datastores
        metadata about the available datastores

        returned: always
        sample:
        - accessible: true
          capacity: 5497558138880
          datastore_cluster: datacluster0
          freeSpace: 4279000641536
          maintenanceMode: normal
          multipleHostAccess: true
          name: datastore3
          nfs_path: /vol/datastore3
          nfs_server: nfs_server1
          provisioned: 1708109410304
          type: NFS
          uncommitted: 489551912960
          url: ds:///vmfs/volumes/420b3e73-67070776/
```

Can anyone suggest what was the issue, as I was getting the expected output before and now it is not coming.